# Python recursion, printing values between two integers

Tags: python, recursion

I am wanting to recursively print all integers between two integers given as inputs to the `print_numbers` function.

So far I have gotten:

```
def print_numbers(start,stop):
    if start == stop:
        print(start)
    else:
        print(start)
        print(print_numbers(start + 1,stop))
```

But when calling `print_numbers(1,5)` I get:

```
1
2
3
4
5
None
None
None
None
```

I can't seem to figure out where the none is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are calling `print_between`, `print_between` does not return anything and so when you do `print(print_between(start + 1,stop))`, it prints `None` because the function returns `None`.

Replace

```
print(print_between(start + 1,stop))
```

with

```
print_between(start + 1,stop)
```

Also, make sure your function name is `print_between` and not `print_numbers`

Check out a quick [DEMO](http://repl.it/oUq) here

Comment: Ah I see I had one too many print statements! Silly mistake! Thank you so much I appreciate it (I will accept this answer once I am allowed)

Comment: @ASm, Sure no problem. It is a common confusion to make

Answer (score 2):

The default return value of a function is None. you don't need to print it.

```
def print_numbers(start,stop):
    if start == stop:
        print(start)
    else:
        print(start)
        print_between(start + 1,stop)
```